# Cannot read XML file using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Having issues reading the following XML file that I create.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<prsettings>
<prsetting>
    <players>
        <player>
            <lastDateEntered>0</lastDateEntered>
            <lastTournament>1</lastTournament>
            <playerId>0</playerId>
            <playersStatus>unrated</playersStatus>
            <playersTag>asfd</playersTag>
            <score>5.0</score>
            <setsPlayed>0</setsPlayed>
            <tourneysWhileInactive>0</tourneysWhileInactive>
        </player>
        <player>
            <lastDateEntered>0</lastDateEntered>
            <lastTournament>1</lastTournament>
            <playerId>1</playerId>
            <playersStatus>unrated</playersStatus>
            <playersTag>ba</playersTag>
            <score>5.0</score>
            <setsPlayed>0</setsPlayed>
            <tourneysWhileInactive>0</tourneysWhileInactive>
        </player>
        <player>
            <lastDateEntered>0</lastDateEntered>
            <lastTournament>1</lastTournament>
            <playerId>2</playerId>
            <playersStatus>unrated</playersStatus>
            <playersTag>asdgf</playersTag>
            <score>5.0</score>
            <setsPlayed>0</setsPlayed>
            <tourneysWhileInactive>0</tourneysWhileInactive>
        </player>
    </players>
    <challongeApiKey>asbg</challongeApiKey>
    <challongeUsername>asf</challongeUsername>
    <implementPointDecay>false</implementPointDecay>
    <numSetsNeeded>5</numSetsNeeded>
    <numTourneysForActive>2</numTourneysForActive>
    <numTourneysForInnactive>5</numTourneysForInnactive>
    <numTourneysNeeded>5</numTourneysNeeded>
    <pointsRemoved>5</pointsRemoved>
    <prName>asf</prName>
    <removeInnactive>false</removeInnactive>
    <showPlacingDiff>false</showPlacingDiff>
    <showPointDiff>false</showPointDiff>
    <startOfDecay>3</startOfDecay>
</prsetting>
```

I have an observableList of PRSetting objects and within the PRSetting objects I have an ArrayList of Players. This is why I created a POJO file and within the PRSetting Object the only object I set up was the following.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="players")
@XmlElement(name ="player")
private ArrayList<PlayerProfile> playersList = new ArrayList<PlayerProfile>();
```

Here is also my POJO file that is supposed to be used to write and read the XML file.

```
@XmlRootElement (name = "prsettings")
public class PRSettingsWrapper {
private ObservableList<PRSettings> prList;

@XmlElement(name = "prsetting")
public ObservableList<PRSettings> getPrList(){
    return prList;
}

public void setPrList(ObservableList<PRSettings> prList){
    this.prList = prList;
}
}
```

For some reason whenever I attempt to to load the data with the following code

```
       JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
               .newInstance(PRSettingsWrapper.class);
       Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

       // Reading XML from the file and unmarshalling.
       PRSettingsData wrapper = (PRSettingsData) um.unmarshal(file);

       prList.clear();
       prList.addAll(wrapper.getPrList());

       // Save the file path to the registry.
       setPrSettingsFilePath(file);
```

I cannot seem to successfully load the xml files into the objects. The file path is working correctly, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to mislead you about the cause.

The problem is caused by ObservableList;

You can refer to this article:
[Marshalling ObservableList with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190431/marshalling-observablelist-with-jaxb)

I modified code from the link above, and the followings should be workable.

anotherTest.MyContainer

```
package anotherTest;

import java.util.List;

    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElements;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "prsettings")
    public class MyContainer extends MyObject {

        private ObservableList<MyObject> children = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        @XmlElements({ @XmlElement(name = "prsetting", type = MyObject.class) })
        public List<MyObject> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        public String toString() {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("children:");

            for (MyObject node : children) {
                sb.append("\n");
                sb.append("  " + node.toString());
            }
            return sb.toString();

        }
    }
```

anotherTest.MyObject

```
    package anotherTest;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

    @XmlType(name = "Object")
    public class MyObject {

        private String challongeApiKey;

        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "players")
        private List<PlayerProfile> player;

        public String getChallongeApiKey() {
            return challongeApiKey;
        }

        public void setChallongeApiKey(String challongeApiKey) {
            this.challongeApiKey = challongeApiKey;
        }

        public List<PlayerProfile> getPlayer() {
            return player;
        }

        public void setPlayers(List<PlayerProfile> player) {
            this.player = player;
        }

    }
```

anotherTest.PlayerProfile

```
package anotherTest;

public class PlayerProfile {

    private int playerId;
    private String playersStatus;

    public int getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public void setPlayerId(int playerId) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
    }

    public String getPlayersStatus() {
        return playersStatus;
    }

    public void setPlayersStatus(String playersStatus) {
        this.playersStatus = playersStatus;
    }

}
```

anotherTest.Example

```
package anotherTest;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create container with list
        MyContainer container = new MyContainer();

        // add objects
        MyObject object;

        object = new MyObject();
        object.setChallongeApiKey("ABCABC");
        container.getChildren().add(object);

        PlayerProfile p = new PlayerProfile();
        p.setPlayerId(1);
        p.setPlayersStatus("unrated");

        List<PlayerProfile> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(0, p);

        object.setPlayers(l);

        // marshal
        String baseXml = marshal(container);

        // unmarshal
        container = unmarshal(baseXml);

        System.out.println("unmarshal test: " + container.getChildren().get(0).getChallongeApiKey());
        System.out.println("unmarshal test: " + container.getChildren().get(0).getPlayer().get(0).getPlayerId());
        System.out.println("unmarshal test: " + container.getChildren().get(0).getPlayer().get(0).getPlayersStatus());

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static String marshal(MyContainer base) {

        try {

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyContainer.class);

            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(base, stringWriter);
            String xml = stringWriter.toString();

            System.out.println("XML:\n" + xml);

            return xml;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    public static MyContainer unmarshal(String xml) {

        try {

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyContainer.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);

            MyContainer container = (MyContainer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(stringReader);

            return container;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

the output in the console is

```
XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<prsettings>
    <prsetting>
        <players>
            <player>
                <playerId>1</playerId>
                <playersStatus>unrated</playersStatus>
            </player>
        </players>
        <challongeApiKey>ABCABC</challongeApiKey>
    </prsetting>
</prsettings>

unmarshal test: ABCABC
unmarshal test: 1
unmarshal test: unrated
```

---

Sorry, I don't know why either. I tested that if declare children to `List<MyObject>`, it can work properly. However, when it comes to `ObservableList`, you must declare it like this, or `NullPointerException` will occur when unmarshalling (but the same code works well on marshalling).

```
private ObservableList<MyObject> children = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Comment: I had accidentally copied my XML incorrectly, but it is set up correct after I checked it on the linked site. And my code is practically the same as yours with the exception of you not have the @XmlElement in the PRSettings class above the method, but for some reason it is still not working

Comment: I have also added that JAXBException under my method and it seems as if I'm getting a null pointer exception whenever it begins to unmarshal

Comment: So it reads it perfectly which is awesome, but for some reason writing to the xml the following 
    <players/>
    <challongeApiKey></challongeApiKey> .......
    <startOfDecay>3</startOfDecay> and then it prints out everything perfect. It still reads it fine, so it can work this way, but do you have an idea as to why it might be doing this?  Regardless, thank you for your help!